# Open an URL in actionscript and load the data

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

How would I load a resource (like a JSON or XML document) from the web in ActionScript 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to have a cross-domain policy file to access data that is not hosted on your own domain.

> You cannot load variables or XML data
>   into a Flash movie from another
>   domain. For example, a Flash movie
>   loaded from
>   http://www.yourserver.com/flashmovie.swf
>   can access data residing at
>   http://www.yourserver.com/data.txt.
>   The text file is located within the
>   same domain as the SWF.
>
> However, an attempt to load data from
>   http://www.NotMyServer.com/data.txt
>   will fail and no error messages are
>   displayed. The load action will cause
>   a warning dialog to appear.
>
> Note: This security feature does not
>   affect Flash movies playing in
>   stand-alone projectors.

source: [Cross-domain policy for Flash movies](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html)

once you have that set up, you can access the XML file via a URLLoader like this:

```
var XMLData:XML;

var XMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
XMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, XMLCompleteEventHandler);
XMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://my.xml.file"));

function XMLCompleteEventHandler(evt:Event):void
    {
    evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, XMLCompleteEventHandler);
    XMLData = new XML(evt.currentTarget.data);
    }
```

i'm not sure if JSON files also require a cross-domain policy file, but i assume so.  in either case, you may be able to bypass this security check by employing some JavaScript + ExternalInterface routine.  the cross-domain policy file is not required for AIR applications.

you can find a JSON parser in [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/tree/master/src/com/adobe/serialization)

Comment: +1 A JSON object that has been encoded is a string that is safe for sending over http. And yes all data not on the same domain will need a policy file.

Comment: Using some JavaScript and ExternalInterface can work with JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this and the question has been answered a few times here in various ways.

Try searching for Flash Php communication.

To load an XML document , look for the URLLoader class. 
For JSON, you can look into passing variables via SWFObject, also have a look at Zend Amf Server.